# Disable link in quantity field

Tags: woocommerce

I add this code:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/override-loop-template-and-show-quantities-next-to-add-to-cart-buttons/

for suport quantity field. But there is link href function and when I click on quantity field, so it redirect. How disable it?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), glad to see a new member! Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and make your question a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it with this snippet:

```
// WooCommerce remove the product quantity link
add_action( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_inputmode', 'wcname_close_link', 9);
function wcname_close_link() {
    echo "</a>";
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_inputmode', 'wcname_open_empty_link', 4);
function wcname_open_empty_link() {
    echo "<a href='#'>";
}
```